# Menu is invisible in admin panel but it's visible in front-end

Tags: menus, wp-admin

I am not able to see any menus I added in my website back-end and even I am not able to create a new menu. Though the menu I created earlier is showing.

Please guide me on how I can make it visible so that I can add new pages in main menu. Let me know where I can share my website so that you can help me out. I look forward to hearing from you.

Thanks!

Here is the back end
[image: ![Back end Appearance>menu]

Here is the front end
[image: Front end menu]

Comment: Please share what have you done so far.

Comment: I have added the images of what I have

Answer (score 3):

If you created the theme yourself, you should take a look at the WordPress Codex. They have a section called [Navigation Menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus). It contains all information you need about registering your menus the right way, so they are customizable.

To Keep things short:

Add this code to your theme's functions.php to register your menu:

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Then place this in your theme at the place your menu needs to be:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Change names where needed.

*If did not create the theme yourself.* Then ask the theme author to implement the menu in the right way.

You can also create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and edit the (purchased) theme yourself. Then create two files. The first file should be `functions.php` and add the above code to it. Then duplicate the theme file where the menu is located (probably `header.php`). And change the menu code to the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the response Xvilo. I think the problem is not with the theme because I activated another theme and the issue is still the same. I also deactivated all the plugins. This issue just came out of the blue

Comment: Can you confirm it did work before? Try changing to the WordPress default theme Twenty Seventeen. If you can see it here, it is definitely your theme ;)

Comment: Yes, I changed the theme to WordPress default theme Twenty Seventeen but I still see no changes

Comment: I did take a look at your screenshot again and it seems everything is working fine. You have to create a menu first. Just type your menu name in the input field: https://puu.sh/uewUb/71668b13d9.png. Then press 'create menu' on the right side of the text button. After that you can create your menu.

Comment: When I try adding a new menu, nothing happens. Before it was working well. As you can see on the front end it shows that there is a menu I created but I can't create or edit it in the back end. Nothing happens when I hit create

Comment: This is a nasty situation then. Try disabling all plugins and switch twenty seventeen to if there is an incompatibility with it. Otherwise, you should ask on the WordPress forums since that is the best place for more specific problems.

Comment: I already disabled all the plugins. Nothing shows,,,

Comment: I have updated the back end image..

Comment: Did you ever solve this?
I had the same. I have created a menu, it shows in frontpage, but not in admin.

Comment: Well, I could create a new menu, so it's kind of moot now.